# Where is the userspace used by TUN/TAP?

Tags: virtualization, kvm-virtualization, tun, tap

When I  put  data  on a  wire in qemu what  sets the upper  limit  on the rate of  data  I can transmit?
The  situation is I  set  up two machines A and B

create two tap interfaces

```
openvpn --mktun --dev tap0 --user `id -un`
openvpn --mktun --dev tap1 --user `id -un`
```

bridge between them

```
/usr/sbin/brctl addbr br0
/usr/sbin/brctl addif br0 tap1
/usr/sbin/brctl addif br0 tap0
```

bring up the  bridge

```
/sbin/ifconfig br0 10.0.0.1 netmask 255.255.255.0 broadcast 10.0.0.255
```

I start them with a  tap device

```
qemu -m 256 -hda diskA.img -net nic -net tap,ifname=tap0,script=no
qemu -m 256 -hda diskB.img -net nic -net tap,ifname=tap1,script=no
```

The  tap device  writes data  to a  userspace, but  where is  that  userspace ,what  are  its  constraints and  how  do I  control it?

Comment: Why did you create the tap interface with openvpn? Openvpn is running in this moment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case the userspace application is qemu. TUN/TAP devices are kernel space virtual devices. To control tap interface use ifconfig, ip, brctl etc.

The upper limit of your transmitted data is dictated by your CPU. If you want to control the limit then you should use tcng (traffic control language interpreter).

Also, if you want just to connect the qemu's between them, you can use just 1 tap interface and share it between qemu's.